# How to add an origin repository in Git

Tags: git, github

I want to add a remote origin repository so that when I enter

```
git push origin master
```

It pushes to https://github.com/JGHInternet/tillyoudrop

(to the master branch)

What should the exact command look like for doing this

Comment: Did you clone this repo?

Comment: No. What does clone do?

Comment: Basically it copies the remote project to a local folder on your computer so you can work on it. Then, after you have done some work, if you `git push origin master` it should automatically push to the repository you cloned.

Comment: I have copied the entire application folder to my machine manually, but not using git

Comment: Why not? What did you use?

Comment: I mean I physically copied the folder with all application files, so the application is running on my machine. I used.. uhm.. Finder. haha

Comment: Haha ok :-) you want to use git instead

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:JGHInternet/tillyoudrop
git push -u origin master
```

Take into account that the remote repository has to exist before you push.

Comment: should it be git@github.com or my username? (MarcoPrins@github.com)

Comment: on github it's always git@github

Comment: No way, you worked at Shopstar, me too hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Because the repository already exists on GitHub, you should use git to clone it instead of manually downloading it and copying it into a folder.

Get the 'clone-link' from the GitHub page of the project (I think it's a private repo so I can't get the exact link for you). Then in a terminal navigate to the folder where you want the repo to be cloned to. Then

```
git clone <clone link from github>
touch test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "Added test.txt"
git push origin master
```

This should clone the repository, create a new txt file, commit it and push it.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has a great article on [Pushing to a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote). Check it out.